# cumulative distribution of transformed normal

Tags: distributions, classification, normal-distribution

I am reading a paper, and in that it says if $P(x|y = +1) \sim N(\mu_1,\Sigma_1)$ and $P(x|y = -1) \sim N(\mu_{-1}, \Sigma_{-1})$.  Then if we take the classification $f(x) = a^Tx-b$, then the cumulative distribution $P(ax < b| y = +1) = \Phi(\frac {b-a^T\mu_1} {\sqrt(a^T\Sigma a)})$ where $\Phi$ is the cdf of standard normal distribution.  I know that $P(ax-b|y) = +1 \sim N(a\mu_1 -b, a^T\Sigma_1 a)$.  But how does the cumulative function get that form.

How come they get $b - a^T\mu_1$ in the numerator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the class conditional probability density functions are multivariate normal. We know that, if the random vector $x:p\times 1\sim N_{p}(\mu, \Sigma)$, then every linear combination of the components of $x$ is a univariate normal ransom variable. Let $a:p\times 1$ be a vector of constants. Then $a^{T}x\sim N_{1}(a^{T}\mu,a^{T}\Sigma a)$. Then, by definition,
\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left(a^{T}x < b|y=+1\right) &=&P\left(a^{T}x -a^{T}\mu < b - a^{T}\mu|y=+1\right)\\
&=&P\left(\frac{a^{T}(x-\mu)}{\sqrt{a^{T}\Sigma a}}<\frac{b - a^{T}\mu}{\sqrt{a^{T}\Sigma a}}|y=+1\right)\\
&=&\Phi\left(\frac{b - a^{T}\mu}{\sqrt{a^{T}\Sigma a}}|y=+1\right) 
\end{eqnarray*} 
In the first equation we subtract the mean of the random variable $a^{T}x$ and in the second equation, we divide on both sides by the standard deviation $\sqrt{a^{T}\Sigma a}$ of $a^{T}x$. The quantity $\frac{a^{T}(x-\mu)}{\sqrt{a^{T}\Sigma a}}$ is a standard normal variate, and hence, $\Phi()$.

Answer (score 0):

The cdf itself is just the cdf of any gaussian, which has an integral form. You can follow this link for further information about it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function
As you can see the cdf of a gaussian is this phi with "x-mu" in the numerator and "sigma" in the denominator.
Now because we'd like to evaluate the probability of axmu-b" as "mu" so the numerator is 0-(amu-b)=b-a*mu.

Someone, please edit my math, I'm not familiar with Latex :(